# MySQL query to grab ALL rows that contain duplicate value in "slug" column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This code is looking for the rows that contain the same value in **"slug"** column and grouping them if they are found more than once.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
$sql = " SELECT *, 
         COUNT(slug) 
         FROM cars
         GROUP BY slug
         HAVING ( COUNT(slug) > 1 )";
$q   = $this->db->query($sql);
return $q;
```

The problem is that instead of:

```
blue-volkswagen-2001
blue-volkswagen-2001
red-toyota-1989
red-toyota-1989
red-toyota-1989
green-mercedes-50
green-mercedes-50
```

I am getting this:

```
blue-volkswagen-2001
red-toyota-1989
green-mercedes-50
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong and why only the first row is grabbed instead of all duplicates?

I have asked this question on CodeIgniter forum, but they didn't know how to do this so I can accept a custom SQL query from some SQl guru instead of Active Record, because that's probably not possible to achieve with Active Record.

Comment: possible duplicate of [group by eliminates other results and leave only the first when using get() in CodeInginter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241183/group-by-eliminates-other-results-and-leave-only-the-first-when-using-get-in-c)

Comment: Please stop spamming with same question. If people can help they will answer you on the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241183/group-by-eliminates-other-results-and-leave-only-the-first-when-using-get-in-c)

Comment: Do you have an id auto increment?post the table schema.

Comment: @MihaiIorga Now I am asking completely different thing. Read the question, thanks. I am approaching it from a different way. You can delet my question in CodeIgniter forum if you want. But this question is different.

Comment: Yes, of course I am using this table for CRUD operation and it works. ID is PRimary key, AUTO_INCREMENT and INT

Comment: @MihaiIorga I have updated my SQL code for grabing values. Please check it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` with a `subquery` to achieve this.

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.total_count FROM cars a INNER JOIN (SELECT slug, count(*) as total_count FROM cars GROUP BY slug HAVING count(slug) > 1 ) b ON a.slug = b.slug WHERE  b.total_count > 1";
$output   = $this->db->query($query );
```

Do index `slug` column to improve performance.

This will give the output like the way you want.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Finally some SQL guru helped. Thanks a lot it's working ;D

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE slug IN ( SELECT slug FROM vehicle GROUP BY slug
HAVING ( COUNT(slug) > 1 ) )
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e2be2/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(slug)
    FROM cars
    GROUP BY slug
    HAVING COUNT(slug) > 1
```